# How to delete a closed question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

My recent question on Stack Overflow was made a community wiki and was closed by some people.

Is it possible to delete that question?

I really want to do it. Would appreciate if somebody helps me out.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: I think the OP probably means this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593928/difference-between-coding-in-java-c-and-python-closed

Comment: FYI - it's not a CW. Personally, I see nothing wrong with this question. You might consider editing it to make it a CW (which kind of makes you not the owner), and leaving it up.

Comment: Every time a question with such great answers as that gets closed a little kitten dies. Seriously. It's so discouraging to see this happen over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to your question

You can flag it for ♦ attention and ask for it to be deleted. If there are no upvoted answers (IIRC), you can delete it yourself, there's a "delete" link below it.

### Answer to your situation

You don't have to get a question deleted just because it's been closed. I've seen people delete questions when it gets closed/answered in the comments.

Remember, closing is supposed to be a temporary time-out (usually for NARQ/localized, sometimes for OT and NC, and not usually for dupe). A closed question (unless it is a dupe) is supposed to be edited, improved, and reopened. It's only liable to deletion *if it isn't salvageable*. I'm not sure of the policy for deleting dupes, I personally find dupes useful when searching.

In this case, the question was of the [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) type, and probably unsalvageable (looking at the title, since I don't have 10k on SO). So yes, it probably deserved a historical lock or a deletion in this case.

But please do not delete all your closed questions. I see users who self delete when a salvageable question is closed (also when it gets answered in the comments); this is bad.